# One tableview with two tableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to link two and more `tableviewcontroller` (as needed ) in one tableview.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selected = table[indexPath.row].type
    switch selected {
    case "Pickles":
        let VC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cell2") as! SecondTableController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
        VC.Pickler()
    case "Dough" :
        let VC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cell2") as! thirdTableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
        VC.Pickler()
    default:
        break
    }
```

It shows:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController'

Comment: It's hard to understand for me what do you trying to achive. Do you want to show different view controllers depending on cell?

Comment: Sorry I've not been clear, I mean using two or more tableviewcontroller on one tableview as requested

Comment: The way you worded your question is confusing. If I understand you have a tableview, and you want to push one of two different view controllers that each have their own tableview. Firstly you need to point out the exact line of code that is throwing an error. Add an exception break point and run the code. It will show you exactly which line is causing the problem. Secondly, avoid forced unwrapping with "if let" statements. Thirdly, don't start a local variable with a capital letter. It's bad practice.